# Understanding the GROUP BY statement's behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having-clause

The question is this..

Table is this..

```
+--------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| facility_map_id          | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| facility_map_facility_id | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| facility_map_listing_id  | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Data is this..

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
| facility_map_id | facility_map_facility_id | facility_map_listing_id |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
|             248 |                        1 |                      18 |
|             259 |                        1 |                      19 |
|             206 |                        1 |                      20 |
|             244 |                        1 |                      21 |
|             249 |                        2 |                      18 |
|             207 |                        2 |                      20 |
|             208 |                        3 |                      20 |
|             245 |                        3 |                      21 |
|             260 |                        4 |                      19 |
|             261 |                        5 |                      19 |
|             246 |                        6 |                      21 |
|             250 |                        7 |                      18 |
|             247 |                        8 |                      21 |
+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I run the this query :

```
SELECT facility_map_listing_id 
FROM facility_map 
WHERE facility_map_facility_id IN(1, 2) 
GROUP BY facility_map_listing_id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT facility_map_facility_id) >= 2
```

and get this..

```
+-------------------------+
| facility_map_listing_id |
+-------------------------+
|                      18 |
|                      20 |
+-------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is correct! - but can anyone explain, why the GROUP BY needs to be in the statement?

if it Isnt and I run the same query leaving out the GROUP BY I get..

```
+-------------------------+
| facility_map_listing_id |
+-------------------------+
|                      18 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can any one explain this to me? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a `group by`, an aggregate like `count` works on the set as a whole.  So this query returns either zero or one row:

```
SELECT facility_map_listing_id 
FROM facility_map 
WHERE facility_map_facility_id IN(1, 2)
HAVING count(DISTINCT facility_map_facility_id) >= 2
```

It will return one row if the `having` condition is met, and an empty set otherwise.

Now, with the group by, it evaluates the `having` condition for each value of `facility_map_listing_id`.  That  can return up to as many rows as there are distinct values of `facility_map_listing_id`.

Comment: Brill - explained things perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I think [this](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/9481;pt=9316) should explain things:

> If you omit group by, all the rows not excluded by the where clause
>   return as a single group.

So, basically, you are still using a group by...just by the entire set.

Comment: Thank you for the resource! I understand things much better now. I upped your answer!

Answer (score 1):

**we can** use HAVING clause without a `GROUP BY` clause but `SELECT` columns and `HAVING` columns should be used with aggregate functions:

- AVG() - Returns the average value
- COUNT() - Returns the number of rows
- FIRST() - Returns the first value
- LAST() - Returns the last value
- MAX() - Returns the largest value
- MIN() - Returns the smallest value
- SUM() - Returns the sum

**HAVING** is generally used with the `GROUP BY` clause, and mainly used to manipulate and filter the data by using aggregate functions. *When GROUP BY is not used, HAVING behaves like a WHERE clause.*

**HAVING**  sets conditions for the `group by` clause, similar to the way in which where sets conditions for the select clause.

[See This](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/) 
and [This one](http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/94544.html)